# Cassandra List Data Type C# get the last element

Tags: c#, database, list, cassandra, ienumerable

I have a List in Cassandra DB.
I use the following code to fetch them,

```
 string query = "select name from table where userid = 'abcd' ;";
            try
            {
                Connector connector = new Connector();
                session = connector.Connect();
                RowSet rows = session.Execute(query);
                if (rows.Columns.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Row row in rows)
                    {
                        data = row["name"].ToString();
                    }
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // no rows
            }
            session.Cluster.Shutdown();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

I need to convert this list object which is converting to string as of now to arrays so that I can fetch the last string as needed.

Is there any inbuilt method to do same?

Comment: where is list object?

Comment: Do you want this ? rows[rows.Length -1] ["name"].ToString()?

Comment: Wanted to convert to object also. i did it

Comment: let us know your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code at last

```
                foreach (Row row in rows)
            {

               object a = row["name"];
                string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)a).Cast<object>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                 .ToArray();
                int ab = arr.Length;
             /*for all items*/
                for(int i=0; i<ab;i++)
                {
                    ltr.AppendText(arr[i]+","+i+" | ");
                }
/*for only last item*/
            string lastItem = arraystring[length - 1];

            }
```

Combined many answers and did this and it works for me. let me know if there is any play with Enumerable method.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a Cassandra `list<string>` into a .NET `List<T>` using the `Row.GetValue<T>()` method:

```
var list = row.GetValue<List<string>>("name");
string lastValue = list[list.Count - 1];
```

Comment: Possible, but did not try it out. am happy with the answer i posted as it can give any element needed.